# Force Computer to use LAN instead of Wifi Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb, router

On my computer I can connect to a wireless network and I use USB internet (Dongle). I would like to dedicate my computer to use the USB Dongle only and not the WiFi at all.. this is because I use connectify (Software) to broadcast the WiFi network and connect my PS3 to the internet and when I do it now the computer uses the WiFi network as well sometimes and creates LAG on my PS3.

Please Help !
Windows 8

Comment: Is this on Windows 7 or 8? You say one in the text but have the tag for the other.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you need to turn off wireless, your computer will fall back to wired and you will continue to have Internet connectivity.

Windows 8 has several different ways you could do this, in summary you will be opening the "Wireless" option and sliding the bar to "off"  If you don't know how to do this the link below has detailed instructions for both a laptop and a tablet.

[Windows 8 Detailed Instructions](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3448449/how-turn-of-wi-fi-bluetooth-in-windows-8/)

If you actually have Windows 7 or don't know what version of Windows you have just respond and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.